# Is it possible to create a view in CartoDB through the UI?

Tags: postgresql, carto

We have some datasets in CartoDB.  I'd like to create a view (in the SQL sense of the word) over one of them, but I can't see how.

When I click the New Dataset button, it seems I only have the option to import data from somewhere.

[image: Carto UI - create dataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create VIEWS using traditional SQL, just use the SQL panel of dataset view on the EDITOR or BUILDER interfaces. Mind that they won't appear on your datasets list but still they are available for your maps definitions.